# How to set up the apps key in conemu so it doesn't open the mintty menu

Tags: cygwin, conemu, mintty

I use Conemu and Cygwin at home and at work, and I was trying to get the keyboard and highlighting to behave the same way in both places, so I imported my home Conemu settings file into my work Conemu, and now I've lost my ability to use Apps+PgDn/PgUp to scroll the backbuffer.  Instead, when I press the Apps key, the mintty menu pops up.

How do I get that back?

Comment: Almost unbelievable. Compare what process do you start in Tab at work and at home.

Comment: Ok, I will look into that.  Thanks!

Comment: @Maximus: I checked and the processes are the same.  I'm using "C:\cygwin\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -", which I think I copied from the shortcut the cygwin installer creates.  I reloaded my old settings and it restored the functionality.  Yet all the settings on the Keyboard page are the same!  And in both settings, the Apps+PgUp/PgDn are configured to their defaults (scroll up/down).  Where is the setting that specifies where the Apps key should go?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out that the problem is mintty.exe.  I think they changed it in Windows 10 so the Apps/Menu key makes the context menu pop up, and there doesn't seem to be any way to disable that.  I'm using Windows 8 at work and Windows 10 at home, hence the disparity.

If you just set your task to run bash.exe, everything seem to work fine.

Now that I figured it out, I can see why running mintty.exe in ConEmu doesn't make much sense, since they're kind of competing products, both designed to be better alternatives to cmd.exe.

There are only a couple of differences:
bash.exe has no way to specify an icon, but that easily fixed by putting `/icon "C:\cygwin\Cygwin-Terminal.ico"` (or whatever your cygwin icon path is) in ConEmu's task parameters.

The color scheme is also different, but appending `-new_console:P:"<Standard VGA>"` to the task command makes it the same as mintty.exe's (I want ConEmu to run Far Manager with the `<Solarized>` color scheme).